# React front end connected to node.js backend with only 1 port open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, port

I am having a pretty big problem at work and would like some help. Basically I have a react front end and a node.js backend to connect to the database. The problem is that the company I am buildign this for will only open 1 port (443) for the webpage. And since react is generating on the clients side I cant use a localhost url to call the backend to get info from the database. They said they might open another port if we make it HTTPS. So I tried using express and https with a self assigned ssl certificate, which worked on my side. On the clients end the webpage's http call doesnt make it to the express server.

I have also started to build this with webpack and express, so the server will render the react code. This should work but I am suspecting a problem with webpack (have not had a good experience with it in the past).... Anyways, is there anything one of yall can think about that will allow my client rendered react app to connect to the database? How do other companies handle something like this? Really any help would be great. I have been under so much stress from this.

If you think you have any information that could help point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to open any other port to access the database, since the code that will access it will run server-side. I mean, yes the database port will need to be open locally, but it does not need to be open to the Internet.

In other words, you will need to have your react code access an API on your server (https end-point on port 443) in order to retrieve data. Your solution with Express should work. I guess you have a Node server listening on port 443, and that you are using Express as framework server-side. It is this server side code what should access the database and provide the data to https requests made by your React client-side code. Your browser might not like your self-signed certificate, and you will probably need to tell it to trust the certificate.

UPDATE:

If you want to block all ports from the server except port 443, you can use a firewall to achieve that, and make the ports look inactive, except for request coming from localhost, the server itself. If that's not an option, you could also choose to connect to the database using a socket path instead of a TCP port.

Comment: Yeah the api is working fine. Its getting the webpage to get to that end point that is the problem. Since its rendered client side, I cant use localhost and since they dont have another port open I cant call it by the ip or url of the server

Comment: @JesseBurnley I am not sure I understand why your web page cannot access the end-point... Can you give more details, please?

Comment: the webpage is being served on one port and I have to use a node js program to access the database. Since this nodejs api is running at the same time, it needs to be on another port. BUT no other ports are open there is no way for someone accessing the front end to actually connect with that api.

Comment: @JesseBurnley What you need on the server is a firewall that will make the database port accessible for connections from localhost but not from the internet. I think your client will need to understand that.

Comment: @JesseBurnley What type of database are you using? Maybe you could use a socket connection instead to access it.